# Make a function depending from x that is the sum of other similar functions depending from x but with different coefficients

Tags: python, function, loops

How to write a function in python that will add the functions, depending on x in a loop, differing only in coefficients? I need to get long function, which is the summation of up to 60 almost similar terms. Coefficients should be taken from tuples. The number of terms depends on the number of elements in the tuples (they have the same number of elements C stands for concentration, T stands for time).
I need to get this function to find the x at which the function takes the minimum value. For example: I want to get a loop instead of writing my function by hand (C[0] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[0]*x) + 195.21*T[0]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[1] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[1]*x) + 195.21*T[1]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 +  (C[2] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[2]*x) + 195.21*T[2]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[3] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[3]*x) + 195.21*T[3]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[4] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[4]*x) + 195.21*T[4]/x + C[0]/x+C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[5] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[5]*x) + 195.21*T[5]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[6] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[6]*x) + 195.21*T[6]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[7] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[7]*x) + 195.21*T[7]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[8] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[8]*x) + 195.21*T[8]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[9] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[9]*x) + 195.21*T[9]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2 + (C[10] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[10]*x) + 195.21*T[10]/x + C[0]/x + C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2

```
from scipy import *
from scipy.optimize import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
x=np.arange(1,50, 0.001)
C = [860, 1090, 1020, 1060, 1070, 1120, 1030, 900]
T = [0, 0.03, 0.07, 0.1, 0.13, 0.15, 0.17, 0.18]

for i in range(len(C)):
   def f(x):
       return (C[i] - (C[0]*np.exp(-T[i]*x) + 195.21*T[i]/x + C[0]/x 
+ C[0] - 195.21/(x*x)))**2
          
   def g(x):
       return (f(i))+(f(i+1))


result = minimize(g, 1)
print (result)
plt.plot(x,g(x))
```

Comment: Don't define your functions inside a loop. _Define them before_ the loop and _execute them inside_ the loop. Functions are meant to be reused after being defined once.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try)